# Calling methods on an object instantiated in a previous method (Java)

Tags: java, object, methods

To put it simply, I have the following code:

```
public void dance()
{
CartoonFigure dancer = new CartoonFigure("rico", 300, 300);
danceStepTwo();
danceStepOne();
}

public void danceStepOne()
{
    dancer.turnLeft();
}

public void danceStepTwo()
{
   dancer.turnLeft();
}
```

but calling these methods on the dancer object give me a compile error 'cannot find symbol -  variable dancer.' How can I fix this so I can call methods of the dancer object from danceStepOne() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define dancer as an instance variable so that it becomes available to both the methods. Else pass its instance to both the methods.

Comment: very helpful thank you. in this case it is easier for me to pass it's instance to both methods

Answer (score 0):

Declare `dancer` as a field variable. Put it (on top) outside any method along with a scope declaration, e.g. `private CartoonFigure dancer`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make `dancer` global, and this error is due to the fact that it's only visible to the method `dance()`, make it an instance field as follows.

```
private CartoonFigure dancer;
```

Initializing it can be done in the constructor as follows

```
dancer = new CartoonFigure("rico", 300, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

As "dancer" object is unavailable for "danceStepOne" and "danceStepTwo", it cannot recognize and will give compilation failure.

For this, any of solution will work

1. Pass it as variable to the method
2. Declare "dancer" as global variable